# Cleanly stop a python thread on keyboard break exit

Tags: python, multithreading, kill

I am using python threading to check a local SQL database for a change in a value.  I have error handling on the main programme to handle a Ctrl+C keyboard break.  This stops the main code but the thread carries on.  How should I stop the thread cleanly when ctlr+c is pressed.  Thanks.
Thread is this:

```
def getVars():
    global setTemp
    global pidControl
    while True:
        dB = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",
                             user="pythonUser",
                             passwd="password123",
                             db="pythonProg")

        cur = dB.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM PiBQ_Temp WHERE tempKey = 1")
        for field in cur:
            fetchTemp = field[1]
            print ("Thread getVars checked temp: " + fetchTemp)

        # Check to see if fetchTemp is different to setTemp and update pid if needed
        if fetchTemp != setTemp:
            setTemp = fetchTemp
            pidControl.setPoint(setTemp)
        time.sleep(5)
```

It is called within the main `try:` statement by this:

```
# Start the getVars thread
t = threading.Thread(target=getVars, args=())
t.start()
print "Thread started: getVars"
```

The error handling is this:

```
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    os.system('clear')
    print ('ctrl+C pressed. \nProgramme complete')
    dB.commit()
    dB.close()
    screen.lcd_cleanup()
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One usual way is to create a global variable, e.g. `pendingExit = False` and set it to `True` in the `except` handler and then `join` the worker thread to wait for its end.

The worker thread in `getVars` must then periodically check `pendingExit` and end.